# How to set an external webcam as the default webcam

Tags: webcam, devices, camera

I have 2 webcams

- an integrated camera on `/dev/video0`
- an external webcam on `/dev/video1`

Softwares using my webcam will choose my integrated camera.

How do I modify my devices in order for my external webcam to be recognized as the main one?